# What is the functional difference between addProduct & addProductImpression in GAIDictionaryBuilder (Google Analytics iOS SDK 3.10)

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics iOS SDK 3.10 and am trying to use the Enhanced ECommerce.  I am confused about the functional difference between

```
- (GAIDictionaryBuilder *)addProduct:(GAIEcommerceProduct *)product;
```

and

```
- (GAIDictionaryBuilder *)addProductImpression:(GAIEcommerceProduct*) productimpressionList:(NSString *)name impressionSource:(NSString *)source;
```

Specifically I am trying to track an impression when a user is viewing the product on a detail view screen.  Therefore, I don't see why specifying a product impression list in neccessary since there is no list.
It appears from the Google Docs that `addProduct:` does the same function but without the "list" attribute.

I realize that I could simple pass an empty string to `addProductImpression`.  However, does anyone know if `addProduct` will give me the same result without the excess code?